# Product measure and independence

Tags: real-analysis, probability, functional-analysis, measure-theory

What's the difference between product measure and independence in probability?
$$
(\mu_1\times\mu_2)(B_1\times B_2)= \mu_1(B_1)\mu_2(B_2)
$$

$$
P(A_m\cap A_k)= P(A_m)P(A_k)
$$
Are product measure it self independent?

Answer (score 6):

There is an equivalence in the following sense.

- Suppose $(\Omega,\mathscr{F},\mathbb{P})$ is a probability space.
- Let $X=\{X_j:j\in J\}$ be a collection of random variables taking values in spaces $(S_j,\mathscr{S}_j)$.
- For each $j$, let $\mu_j=\mathbb{P}\circ X^{-1}_j$ be the law of $X_j$, that is $\mu_j(B)=\mathbb{P}[X_j\in B]$ for any $B\in\mathscr{S}_j$.

1. If $J$ is finite then $\{X_j:j\in J\}$ is independent (i.e., for any $J'\subset J$ and sets $B_j\in\mathscr{S_j}$, $j\in J'$,
   $$\mathbb{P}\Big[\bigcap_{j\in J'}\{X_j\in B_j\}\Big]=\prod_{j\in J'}\mathbb{P}[X_j\in B_j]\tag{1}\label{one}$$
   ) if and only if the (joint) law of $X=\{X_j:j\in J\}$ is the product measure $\bigotimes_{j\in J}\mu_j$.
2. If $J$ is an arbitrary set (finite or infinite), and each space $(S_j,\mathscr{S}_j)$ is nice (a separable metric space with its Borel $\sigma$-algebra for instance; $\mathbb{R}$ with its Borel $\sigma$--algebra for example), then $\{X_j:j\in J\}$ is independent (i.e. $\eqref{one}$ holds for any finite collection $J'\subset J$) then the law of $X=\{X_j:j\in J\}$ is the product measure $\bigotimes_{j\in J}\mu_j$ .

---

The proof of (2) follows from Kolmogorov's extension theorem. The "nice" condition is needed in order to appeal to measure theoretic results that guarantee existence of a unique measure in an arbitrary product of  probability spaces that satisfy a projection property.

**Leo Breiman's** on Probability is an excellent source where the details are explained in a very elegant way.

Comment: I guess you meant to write $\mu_j=\mathbb{P}X_j^{-1}$ ?

Comment: @Arthur: yes, I just made an edit. Thanks!

Comment: Why do you need *niceness*? The map $X:\Omega\to \prod_{j\in J} S_j$, $\omega\mapsto (X_j(\omega))_{j\in J}$ is meaurable and the law $\mu$ of $X$ is thus a probability measure on the product $S$ which is a product of the $\mu_j$ if and only if the family is independent. 

Kolmogorov's theorem is only needed to prove the **existence** of independent random variables with given laws.

Comment: It is rather technical, see Kallenberg's foundations or Breiman's Probability. Niceness means the the spaces are Borel (measurable isomorphic to the unit interval $((0,1),\mathcal{B}(0,1))$) There you can derive uniform distributed random variables and generate any probability measure as well as transfer probabilities. In other approaches, Borel spaces allow you to appeal to the Riesz representation theorem. Notice that in my setting, I consider arbitrary products.

Comment: @Mittens Excellent answer, thanks. I think $\subset$ should be replaced by $\subseteq$. Also it seems that the phrase "then the law of" should be "if the law of" or perhaps "if and only if the law of".

Answer (score 1):

Independence of two random variables means the joint measure induced by them both can be factorized. At a very basic heruistic level, if you have random variable $X$, then it introduces a probability density function $f_{X}$ on the sample space $D$. We need to assume $f_{X}$ is measurable (so it work nicely) and there exists an associated measure $\mu_{X}$ such that
$$
\int_{D}h(x)f_{X}dx=\int_{D}g(x)(\mu_{X} dx), \forall h\in L^{1}(D)
$$
Now the independence of $X,Y$, as two random variables just means the induced measure of $Z=(X,Y)$ on $D\times D$ factorizes:
$$
\mu_{(X,Y)}=\mu_{X}*\mu_{Y}
$$
Without the measure theory jargon, this means that we have
$$
P(X\in E_{i},Y\in E_{j})=P(X\in E_{i})*P(Y\in E_{j}), E_{i}, E_{j}\subset D
$$
where $E_{i},E_{j}$ are any measurable (nicely behaved) subsets of $D$.

You can find a lot more expert input from this [blogpost](https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2010/01/01/254a-notes-0-a-review-of-probability-theory/) written by a real master.